# struts2 + jfreechart + jsp : lost request parameters in action which generates Jfreechart

Tags: struts2, request, jfreechart

1)I called action which generates jfreechart using next jsp(using tiles) code :

```
<s:url  var="chart" action="resultChart"/>
<img src="<s:property value="%{chart}"/>"/>
```

2)struts.xml

```
<package name="chart" extends="jfreechart-default" namespace="/">

    <action name="resultChart" class="com.examples.actions.ChartAction">
        <result name="success" type="chart"> 
            <param name="width"> 1200 </param> 
            <param name="height"> 600 </param>
        </result>
    </action>

</package>
```

3)to generate chart - I use request parameters from previous action :

```
public class ChartAction extends ActionSupport implements RequestAware {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Map request;

    private JFreeChart chart;   

    public String execute() throws Exception {


        DataBean dataBean = (DataBean)request.get("dataBean");
                .....
        }
```

My problem next : I cant draw chart because request return null(dataBean=null)
NOTE : Without passing request parameters all works fine

My research - I used next code in ChartAction(before request.get) to investigate problem:

```
ValueStack valuestack = ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack();

System.out.println("valuestack.size() = " + valuestack.size());

System.out.println("valuestack root = " + valuestack.getRoot().toString());
```

And I saw that in ValueStack no records from action which put parameter(dataBean) into request

Please help

Comment: What's `dataBean`? If it's a new request why would there be anything from a prior request?

Comment: What's dataBean? - dataBean is a JavaBean object

Comment: If it's a new request why would there be anything from a prior request? In previous Action I put this "dataBean" into request : dataBean.setPeriod(period);
...  
request.put("dataBean", dataBean);

Comment: ... Obviously it's a JavaBean (or at least an object). That tells us nothing about how it's set, where, what's in it, etc. Again: why would an object in a *prior* request be in a *new* request???

Comment: The MAIN Problem is that - I cant access to request or session parameters from action which called from jsp; if action called in chain(defined in struts.xml all works ok, but if action called from jsp - request dont work) Please explain how can I pass JavaBeans objects between this actions in situations when one action called from jsp

Comment: You can't; it's a *new request*.

Comment: You can't; it's a new request. - OK, => how can I transfer data objects between this 2 actions??